# Elmah Raise() records inner exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, elmah

I'm trying to raise an exception using Elmah like this:

```
try
{
    Foo();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    var nex = new Exception("Foo failed", ex);
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(nex);
}
```

However, what Elmah records is the inner exception `ex`, not my new wrapper exception `nex`, i.e. the resulting database record has:

`Type = "System.Net.WebException"`, `Message = "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."`

rather than, as I would expect:

`Type = "System.Exception"`, `Message = "Foo failed"`

What on earth's going on?

Comment: where is your configuration for elmah?

Comment: in the web.config

Comment: Can you recreate this in a test project?

Comment: would you please  add the config settings .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELMAH shows the type of the inner exception on the list of exceptions (`/elmah.axd`). If you click the Details link next to the error message, I'm pretty sure you'll see something like this:

`System.Exception: Foo failed ---> System.Net.WebException`

I just created a test project and verified that this is the experienced behaviour.

**Edit:** As discussed in comments, use of the base exception in the Type and Message fields appears to be the [intended behavior](https://github.com/elmah/Elmah/blob/1x/src/Error.cs#L91).

Comment: The detail page does show the wrapper exception as you have described, which comes from the Detail attribute of the AllXml collumn it seems. However the  Type and Message fields which are what are shown in the list view are for the inner exception only.

Comment: I believe this is the intended behavior: https://github.com/elmah/Elmah/blob/1x/src/Error.cs#L91

Comment: So it appears, that seems a strange choice to me, but there you go.

Comment: Maybe. And maybe not :) The base exception is in fact from where the error originated. The outer exception could be a WebException, AggregateException or similar with not much info on its own. It's a matter of taste maybe, but I can see why they would dig into the base exception.